# Laravel validation for uniques value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have multiple customers ,and each customers can have a list of names (customers_name) that can be "aka" or "previous" and for each type value must be unique. *Message: "Call to a member function pluck() on array"*

[image]

```
$customerPrevious = [];
if($customer_name['name_type'] == 'previous'){
    //  previous customer_names from server
    $customerPrevious = $customer->customerNames()->where('name_type', '=', 'previous')->pluck('name')->toArray();
    //  previous customer_names from request
    $customerPreviousRequest = $request->customer_names->where('name_type', '=', 'previous')->pluck('name')->toArray(); 
    $duplicateValue = array_diff($customerPrevious,$customerPreviousRequest);

    if($duplicateValue.length){
            return response($exception->getMessage(), 404);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because inside `$request->customer_names` you get array.

`->pluck()` is for collections.

So you can change:

```
$request->customer_names->pluck('name')
```

with

```
Arr::pluck($request->customer_names, 'name')
```

More about `Arr::pluck()` you can find [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-array-pluck).

Comment: Ok, but now I can't use where for name_type ,from what I saw

Comment: I solved your problem based on your error message. If you need to do `where` you need your array as a collection. You can do that simply with `collect($request->customer_names)`. More you can find [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#creating-collections). Then you will be able to do `->pluck()` on collection. I think thats it. :)